# show data based on current_user() mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working on a solution to show data from tables from my `MySQL` database based on `current_user()`. I have created another table that contains rights that users have, which is linked to the `wp_users` table.

Is there a way to do this via MYSQL, or do I need to use PHP?

So far I have:

```
SELECT ww_id FROM
  (SELECT rechten_ww_id 
     FROM tRechten as T1 
     JOIN wp_users as T2 ON T1.rechten_user_pass=T2.user_pass) as T12
JOIN vWW as T3 ON T12.rechten_ww_id=T3.ww_id where current_user() = ?????
```

Comment: There is way to do conditionals directly in mysql, but php is the better choice

Comment: Can you perhaps  help me with a simple query that I can work with?

Comment: `CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END` literally copied from mysql developer documentation

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL function called `CURRENT_USER()` is not very useful in a WordPress context, because it deals with the user id with which your WordPress instance is logged into MySQL. That's hard-coded into `wp_config.php` in your web site directory. It never changes -- WordPress always uses the same credentials to access MySQL, regardless of which user, or none, is logged into WordPress.

If you want to  make use of the identities of WordPress users, you'll want to use the `wp_users.ID` column as the user's identifier. For example, you can tell which user created each post by looking at the user id value in `wp_posts.post_author`.

The WordPress [function called `get_current_user_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id) lets you fetch the id of the currently logged in WordPress user in a php program. You can then look for posts by matching that user to `wp_posts.post_author`, for example.

Comment: How can I use the get_current_user_id() as it does not work in MYSQL. Sorry, bit of a rookie.

Comment: `get_current_user()` is a php function that's provided by the WordPress infrastructure. You'll call that someplace in the same program you'll use to issue your query.